# Spy Scroll Issue

Tags: scroll, timeline, scrollspy

I am making a webpage with a "time line" style, it's navigated horizontally but has a fixed menu with an element that slides along a bar when you click on every element.

Now I was using a blueprint of vertical timeline that also moved the element across the bar when you got to the element by scrolling normally
http://www.webdesigncrowd.com/demo/slider-timeline-menu-12.2.13/

Now, I am using a page-wrap div to keep the elements within a certain boundary along with a css style for the body to stack elements horizontally.
When I click on ever  it takes me to the correct page like normal, and the bar element works as intended, but the feature for it to work when the linked element moves into view doesn't seem to work anymore

This is the original JS code

```js
 // Scroll Spy
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var top = $(window).scrollTop() + 100; // Take into account height of fixed menu
   $(".container").each(function() {
     var c_top = $(this).offset().top;
     var c_bot = c_top + $(this).height();
     var hash = $(this).attr("id");
     var li_tag = $('a[href$="' + hash + '"]').parent();
     if ((top > c_top) && (top < c_bot)) {

       if (li_tag.hasClass("active")) {
         return false;
       } else {
         li_tag.siblings().andSelf().removeClass("active");
         li_tag.addClass("active");
         $(".menu ul li.active a").slideToPos();
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

And this is what I edited to try to make it work on a Horizontal display.

```js
 // Scroll Spy
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var left = $(window).scrollLeft() + 1300; // Take into account height of fixed menu
   $(".container").each(function() {
     var c_Left = $(this).offset().left;
     var c_bot = c_left + $(this).width();
     var hash = $(this).attr("id");
     var li_tag = $('a[href$="' + hash + '"]').parent();
     if ((left > c_Left) && (left < c_bot)) {

       if (li_tag.hasClass("active")) {
         return false;
       } else {
         li_tag.siblings().andSelf().removeClass("active");
         li_tag.addClass("active");
         $(".menu ul li.active a .navut").slideToPos();
       }
     }
   });
 });
```

Now I have tried using the original one without change too, but that feature is still not working.

I thank you guys in advance.